# Java: Bits -> Bytes -> String Encoding

Tags: java, encoding, byte, utf

In Java, I have a String of bits e.g. "01100111000111...". Next, I want to do the following:

1. convert string to byte array which I have successfully done using:
   `byte[] bytes = new BigInteger(bits, 2).toByteArray();`
2. Next, I want to convert bytes to String which I tried to do using:
   `String byteString = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");`
   but the results are not correct (garbage characters etc.).

I think "UTF-8" is not the proper encoding.

Kindly tell if there is any other way to get the string from such bytes or the proper encoding.

Comment: I think "US-ASCII" would work.

Comment: so you can provide your own answer for your question :-)

Comment: Well, No. Just thought but it did not work. So yes, answer still required.

Comment: if you don't have the encoding, the best you can do is to try them and inspect the results until you figure out what's the correct one

Comment: FWIW, I started with the string "011000010110001001100011" and ran through your code with it. I got the expected output "abc". So you're doing it right, but you may well have the wrong encoding. You'll have to hunt around, I'm afraid... but I'd recommend starting with the ones listed in [`java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html).

Comment: One thing to note, however: if the initial string starts with a 1 and is an even multiple of 8 characters long, then the call `BigInteger(bits, 2).toByteArray()` will end up with a leading `0` in the byte array, which may confuse the subsequent construction of the String.

Answer (score -1):

Edited after your comment:

```
String string = "01100111000111";
byte[] bytes = new BigInteger(string, 2).toByteArray();

String out = "";

for(byte b: bytes)
 out+= String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');

System.out.println(out);
```

output:

```
0001100111000111
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: I think this is somewhat openSource has suggested above. But the question is I want string of 1s and 0s to be considered binary not each digit a Bytes. Then 8 bits of string be converted to a binary which be assigned to byte[] which is then needed in String.